# Customers ID's are not in Sequence

Tags: magento2, database

Check below Image for more understanding question.

If Once already created customer removed/deleted than new customer will start with next not previously deleted.

How can i do so that Customer Id's always in sequence ?

Any guide will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is because you have deleted customers who had ids 1,3-23.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, I know this,  What i have to do so that even after deleting customers new will take last insert ID so that grid wont look bad

Comment: This will create issue. Suppose if you delete the id 5 and last inserted id is 10 then mysql insert 11 when you create new customer not the id 5 as entity id is an autoincrement field.

Comment: Is there any way or workaround so that in grid it will show ID in sequence not in broken order ?

Comment: you can work around Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Increment\NumericValue  but mostly it will be bit tricky to achieve what you are asking but do any changes you need to do around this file by overriding the file or using plugin